# getResourceAsStream() doesn't see resource

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to unpack resources from my jar file. The structure of jar looks like this:

```
my.jar
    META-INF
    resources
        my.exe
        my.dll
    my
        namespace
            UnpackResourceFromThisClass.class
```

I want to unpack my.exe and my.dll from jar file. I tried to unpack those files using this code:

```
try {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/my.exe")
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(destDir))
    Files.copy(is, os)
    os.close()
    is.close()
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? As a result I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.nio.file.Files.provider(Files.java:65)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:106)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:2884)
    at java_nio_file_Files$copy.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at pl.ydp.gradle.Is2k8Task.getResources(Is2k8Task.groovy:84)
    at pl.ydp.gradle.Is2k8Task.build(Is2k8Task.groovy:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
```

This is groovy code which will be used in gradle custom task.

Comment: I would a) check that the .exe is effectively packaged inside the jar and b) check the `Files.copy()` method, the version that accepts an `InputStream` requires the second parameter to be a `Path` (why this does not cause a compile error is beyond me) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: "why this does not cause a compile error is beyond me" Groovy seems to be casting, the line number in the stack trace indicates the first argument is a Path

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be writing Java...  Not sure if this will get you round your problem, but the above could be written in Groovy as:

```
this.getClass().getResource( '/resources/my.exe' ).withInputStream { ris ->
  new File( destDir ).withOutputStream { fos ->
    fos << ris
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new in groovy sou you're right - his is java code compiled from groovy. I tested this but get this error `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry resources/my.exe not found in C:\workspace-eclipse-juno\Is2k8\repo\pl\ydp\gradle\is2k8\0.9\is2k8-0.9.jar`. I' sure that `my.exe` is in jar file.

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała Really sure?  It sounds like the exe is not in the jar at the time this code is running...  It's not being added later is it?

Comment: This is how I test it: 1. Compile gradle jar with my.exe and my.dll. 2. Publish this jar in local maven repo 3. Run gradle build which loads jar and run task from this jar.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the leading slash, getResourceAsStream will use the absolute path if the first character is a slash.

Comment: I've also tested this without leading slash but it didn't help. As you wrote, using leading slash will load resources using absolute path. As I understand using `/` will load it from jar root dir and without `/` will load them from dir where class exist?

Comment: Try using getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream instead.