# Invalid literal/length code - how to solve this?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm totally new in groovy and I want to unpack resources from jar file. I tried it in this way as tim_yates wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16645378/2069368:

```
getClass().getResource('/resources/my.dll').withInputStream {
    is -> new File("my.dll").withOutputStream {
        os -> os << is
    }
}
```

but I get error:

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.leftShift(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:9643)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$458.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
```

I also tried this:

```
getClass().getResource('/resources/my.dll').withInputStream {
    is -> new File("my.dll").withOutputStream {
        os -> Files.copy(is, os)
    }
}
```

but without success. I've checket if `is` is available and it is (`is.available()` returns 914432)

**[EDIT]**

If I will try to copy file in this way it works:

```
new File("C:\\Document.html").withInputStream {
    is -> new File("C:\\Document_Copy.html").withOutputStream {
        os -> os << is
    }
}
```

I'm sure that `my.dll` is in jar file - I load jar from local maven repository. Any idea?

**[ANOTHER EDIT]**

I've added new file `plik.txt` to resources dir. After I run application I get error `JAR entry resources/plik.txt not found in C:\Users\uer\.m2\repository\pl\gradle\is2k8\0.9\is2k8-0.9.jar`. I don't know why I get this error. I checked it and `plik.txt` exists in jar file. I've also entered non existing path, for example `getClass().getResources("/resources/thisdoesntexist.txt")` and I get this error `Cannot invoke method withInputStream() on null object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `getResourceAsStream` to read the contents of a resource file, even in Groovy. If the resource path (inside the Jar) is `resources/my.dll`, and the Jar is on the class path, this should work:

```
def stream = getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/my.dll")
def file = new File("my.dll")
file.delete()
stream.withStream {
    file << stream
}
```