# include php file in final Jar so that method can call php file

Tags: java, php, maven, jar, classpath

I am using a php file from java code like

```
Class JavaPhpTest{
    public void method1(){
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/php/bin/php " + "test.php")
    }
}
```

I included `test.php` ( file reside in `/src/main/resources`) file in `pom.xml` as resource of this java project and after building the `test.php` is there in Jar.

Now when someone use `JavaPhpTest-jar` as dependency in their `pom.xml` and call `method1()` like

```
class javaCall{
public void testing(){
    new JavaPhpTest().method1();
}
```

Problem is that now when i call `testing()`, it gives error that `test.php` is not found.

I see that `JavaPhpTest-jar` is in classpath of javaCall, but no php. 
Could anyone give suggestion how can we solve this dependency problem ?

Should i create a pom project for php as well and include that ? if so, can someone provide me working link to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your issue, because I'm not sure what do you want: read text.php file from JAR or archive whole PHP installation into JAR file

Comment: I am ok with both ways. If we can read php from JAR that would be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute `test.php` you have to read a file content from Jar and save as regular file, in temporary folder. Here you will find examples: [getResourceAsStream() doesn't see resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16645243/2365727)

Then call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)` with path to file in temporal folder

### Update

I saw your solution, it may be simplified:

```
InputStream phpStream = JavaPhpTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.php");
java.nio.file.Files.copy(phpStream, Paths.get("test.php"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked nicely.. Following is the code used : `final String destDir = JavaPhpTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile(); 
         JarFile file = new JarFile(destDir);
         InputStream ipStreamtoPHPFile = file.getInputStream(file.getEntry("test.php"));
         File newfile = new File(destDir + File.separator + "test.php");
         FileOutputStream opStreamPHPfile = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
         
         while (ipStreamtoPHPFile.available() > 0)
            opStreamPHPfile.write(ipStreamtoPHPFile.read());`